# How to update a PDF document opened in a viewer on Windows

Tags: windows, pdf

I am writing a cross-platform application which generates PDF documents and then opens them with the standard PDF viewer. On Linux, updating (re-writing) an already opened document is no problem. The PDF viewer (have tried several) updates the displayed document after overwriting the file. I don't even have to trigger anything. This comes in very handy.

On Windows, however, I cannot overwrite a PDF document opened for reading by some viewer, because the viewers seem to open the document exclusively. Of course I cannot change the code of the viewers like Adobe Reader.

Is there any solution to this? I don't want to clutter the directory with arbitrary new file names, but rather use the same file name again. Deleting of the opened file is also forbidden on Windows.

I cannot determine which PDF viewer is used. In order to open the document, I use

```
cmd.exe /c start <fileName>
```

Comment: just out of my head, can't you terminate the process and re opening the reader? not sure if windows would allow you to do so, but just a guess. What language are you using? If some Visual studio version, might try to see if there is an pdf reader extension, so you can display it inside your application

Comment: The user might have some other documents open in the reader, not only mine. I don't want to interfere with his open applications by killing the process. I am not looking for any language-specific solution, but for the general way of solving the problem, because I am not using any of the popular systems. And I want to allow the user to use the PDF reader he is familiar with, not display PDF in my application. I might display the same data as well in my application, but not the PDF version.